# How to group multiple rules to one rule condition?

Tags: personalization, rules-engine

We are looking on how to consolidate a list of rules under a category or group condition.

So, instead of content editor selecting multiple rules on a component, he/she selects something like `"where groupId matches "GroupA"` on the rule editor.

And define GroupA with a  list of rules, for example,

```
GroupA rules:
where "field1" on userprofile matches "value1" AND
where "field2" on userprofile matches "value2" AND
where "field3" on userprofile matches "value3"
```

I was trying to explore the pattern card way to define GroupA as a pattern but OOTB it does not give an ability to execute based on rule conditions rather works on scores.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are already **predefined rules** in Sitecore. You can create your own rule there and then use it while setting personalization for a component.

Here are the steps:

1. Open in Sitecore `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Personalization/Predefined Rules` item (in older Sitecore versions the item was called `Predefined Conditions`)

[image]

2. Create new item using `Conditional Rendering Rule` template with multiple conditions and give it a meaningful name

[image]

3. Personalize a component using your rule with `Where the predefined rule is equal true` condition

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marek, this is what I was looking for.